# React ASP.NET Core preview project-requests do not resolve to controller other than the WeatherForecast controller

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm using the react asp.net core preview project with Visual Studio 2022. I have created a controller called `WordController`. My `vite.config.js` is shown below.

When I run the application, the `console.log` shows the request still being pushed to `https://localhost:5173/weatherforecast`. How do the request to resolve to my controller?

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [plugin()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        proxy: {
          
            '^/word': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7106/',
                secure: false
            }
         

        },
        port: 5173,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: [Please modify you setting like this](https://codeshare.io/K83Qv8), and tell me if it works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is you haven't change the frontend code in your App.jsx file.

[image]